# Профиксить тест на Python

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Добрый день ребята. Не могу никак профиксить свой тест на python((
в фале main.py добавил код:

```
def main(req):
print('!__REQ:', req)
return "ff"
```

в файл test.py добавил:

```
import unittest

from main import main


class TestMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    REQUEST = {
        "GET_POSTS": """GET /api/v1/posts HTTP/1.1""",
        "POST_POSTS": """POST /api/v1/posts HTTP/1.1

    title=TestTitle1""",
    "GET_404": """GET /api/v1/gimme404 HTTP/1.1""",
}

RESPONSE = {
    "EMPTY_200": """HTTP/1.1 200 OK

    []""",
    "404": "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found",
    "GET_POSTS": """HTTP/1.1 200 OK

    [{"id": "1", "title": "TestTitle1"}]"""
}

def test_empty_get(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.RESPONSE['EMPTY_200'], main(self.REQUEST['GET_POSTS']))

def test_404_get(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.RESPONSE['404'], main(self.REQUEST['GET_404']))


def test_post_and_get(self):
    main(self.REQUEST['POST_POSTS'])
    self.assertEqual(self.RESPONSE['GET_POSTS'], main(self.REQUEST['GET_POSTS']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

и когда я пытаюсь его запустить он выдает мне ошибки вида:

### FAIL: test_404_get (**main**.TestMethods)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ROGER/Desktop/python-test-project/test.py", line 29, in test_404_get
    self.assertEqual(self.RESPONSE['404'], main(self.REQUEST['GET_404']))
AssertionError: 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' != 'ff'
- HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
+ ff
```

Что это могло бы значить?

Comment: В трэйсе же написано, что тест не пройден потому что: 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' != 'ff' - разные значения строк

Comment: Я это перевести тоже могу, но куда копать? что ему не нравится не понимаю

Comment: Вы в тесте сравниваете эквивалентность двух строк. Строки не эквивалентны => тест падает с AssertionError. Не эквивалентны они по причине того, что ваш метод возвращает 'ff', а тест ожидает 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'. Ровно это ему и не нравится, глубоко копать не нужно.

Comment: Я убрал из кода "ff" и оставил чисто return " " и все равно та же ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

В тесте вы пытаетесь сравнить строку HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found со значением, которое возвращает функция main. Сначала вы возвращали ff, и соответственно тест падал, так как "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" != "ff". Позже вы стали возвращать пустую строку, и тест продолжил падать по этой же самой причине. 
Вы сравниваете именно что функция *возвращает*. А вызов команды print работает просто напросто с консолью и не имеет ничего общего с *возвратом*. Прочитайте подробно про то, что такое return, и Вам сразу станет всё понятно!